# VueJS how to update data on selection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In a VueJS 2.0 I want to update the rendering of items using a v-for directive when a selection changes.

html:

```
<main>
 {{ testvalue }}
  <select v-model="selected.name">
    <option v-for="foo in foobar">{{foo.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <span>Selected: {{ selected.name }}</span>
  <div v-for="(value, key) in selected.properties">
    <p>{{ key }} {{ value }}</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

app.js

```
new Vue({
    el: 'main',
    data: {
        foobar: [
      { name: 'rex', type: 'dog', properties: [{color: 'red', sound: 'load'}] },
      { name: 'tike', type: 'cat', properties: [{color: 'brown', sound: 'quiet'}] }, 
      { name: 'tiny', type, 'mouse', properties: [{color: 'white', sound: 'quiet'}]}
      ],
      selected: { name: 'tiny', type, 'mouse', properties: [{color: 'white', sound: 'quiet'}]},
      testvalue: 'Test'
    },
    created: function () {
        this.selected = this.foobar[0];
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.selected = this.foobar[1];
    }
})
```

jsfiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/doritonimo/u1n8x97e/

The v-for directive does not update when the selected object it is getting it's data from changes. Is there a way to tell the v-for loop to update when data changes in Vue?

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle or codepen. The code you provided is incomplete and contains syntax error

Comment: You don't need to tell vue/v-for you have an update. Vue detects changes and re-renders automatically.

Comment: @CodinCat I changed the code and added a fiddle - (but just cant get the fiddle to work..)

Comment: One of the reason it doesn't work is because the data property must be a function. But even then the fiddle doesn't work

Comment: @Potray data property must be a function when using a single file .vue template, not for separated javascript and html as here (I added names for blocks to make clear for others too). My original code actually is written in a single file but I cant get anything to run when I converted it for jsfiddle.

Comment: Data must be a function if you are registering an reusable component. It can be a plain object if you are just creating a new instance with `new Vue(..)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fiddle still contains some typo so it doesn't work.

Please check: https://jsfiddle.net/u1n8x97e/39/

You don't need to store the entire selected object. You can just keep the index.

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option v-for="(foo, i) in foobar" :value="i">{{foo.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Now `selected` is just a number:

```
selected: 0
```

And you access the selected object by `foobar[selected]`