# How to access data from a vue.js method?

Tags: vue.js

I am a rookie to VueJS and I want to update data onclick.
Here is my code:

```
<div id="elementApp">
  <div class="element">{{ message }}</div>
  <button class="button" v-on:click="nextElement()">Next data</button>
</div>

var tempData = [
  {
    message: "A"
  },
  {
    message: "B"
  },
  {
    message: "C"
  }
];

var counter = 0;

var app = new Vue({

  el: '#elementApp',

  data:  tempData[counter],

  methods: {

    nextElement: function () {

      counter += 1;

      this.tempData = tempData[counter];

    }

  }

});
```

I found this answer which is close to what I want but can't manage to transform it: [VueJS how to update data on selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42870285/vuejs-how-to-update-data-on-selection)

I can't see my error… Are methods the wrong way to do it?

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nabuchodonosor/53f1L2gw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this approach should work:

```
var tempData = [
  {
        message: "A"
  },
  {
        message: "B"
  },
  {
        message: "C"
  }
];
var counter = 0;

var app = new Vue({

  el: '#elementApp',

  data:  {
    message: tempData[counter].message
  },

  methods: {
    nextElement: function () {
        counter += 1;
        //that's just to make it safer over the tempData size
        if(counter>=tempData.length)
          counter = 0;
        this.message = tempData[counter].message;
    }
  }
});
```

Doing so, the `nextElement` function on each iteration updates the property `message` of the reactive data of your component.

Hope it helps.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gt4331k2/) you find the fiddle too.

Comment: Gosh! so close and so far… Thank you.